# Change the style of an element nodelist on click event

Tags: javascript, events, dom, nodelist

I have a problem adding an eventlistener to a nodelist on this [website that I'm playing with.](http://coolkeeperbeta.viste-fotografia.com/)

I would like that the **elements with class *card-img-overlay* to change their style on mouseover**.

So the first thing i've tried is adding a for loop, like this:

```
var banner = document.getElementsByClassName("card-img-overlay");

// add a for loop for event listeners on the nodelist
for ( i = 0; i < banner.length; i++) {
    banner[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
 banner[i].style.backgroundColor = "black"});
};
```

And I get the following **error** :

> VM95:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
>       at HTMLDivElement. (:3:12)

How can I add an eventListener to a nodelist in a better way? I didnt learn jQuery yet so i prefer to stick on VanillaJS.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the click event fires it doesn't know what `i` is anymore. You can reference the clicked element with `this`.

```
var banner = document.getElementsByClassName("card-img-overlay");

// add a for loop for event listeners on the nodelist
for ( i = 0; i < banner.length; i++) {
    banner[i].addEventListener("click",function() {
        // function will never know what 'i' is here
        this.style.backgroundColor = "black"
    });
};
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kcr7gLx1/2/

Comment: So the function will never know what "i" is beacuse of scoping? Sorry if I sound stupid but I'm trying to get a good understanding. Thank you very much!

Comment: That is correct. The function inside the click event is anonymous and gets executed outside the scope of the for loop. It is a little confusing.

Comment: That makes sense now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @LucianAndrone Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I am sorry, did not know how to use the platform properly. Thank you!